# jquery carousel for a bootstrap site covering my page on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a carousel I downloaded running on one of my websites.  Every time I scroll to the next window it covers up my navbar.  Also if you scroll down to my price list and wait a moment then when the carousel scrolls it covers the page with a blank div.  Can anybody see why?  Its driving me mental, i'm sure it didn't do this when I first put it on.

I got the carousel here
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/news-carousel

bootsnip is amazing by the way for anybody that uses bootstrap.  My web link is
http://www.parrotplanner.co.uk/

Ive tried looking through google dev tools but cant find anything.  Many thanks guys

Comment: Is there an interaction between the large carousel at the top and the reviews carousel halfway down? I deleted the `#carousel-reviews` div further down in the page and it oddly stopped the dark bar covering the `<nav>`.

Comment: hmmm let me check that and get back to you

Comment: @gempesaw can you put your comment down as a proper answer so I can mark that you solved it?  Many thanks

Comment: Ah, sure! What a weird problem, I was really curious where the bar was coming from and had been just playing around deleting parts of the page until the dark overlay went away :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there an interaction between the large carousel at the top and the second reviews carousel that is halfway down the page ? When I deleted the `#carousel-reviews` div further down in the page, it oddly stopped the dark bar covering the `<nav>`.

Comment: I have no idea what the problem was but thank you.  I can live without that second one for now ;)  I'll replace it with an entirely different one for now.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same in my site dynamichealthit.com
I think is Google Chrome issue, so maybe we need to wait for their upgrates.
Also you can eliminate the carousel.

Comment: I solve using style="position:relative;z-index:999" in the container that hide the content.

Answer (score 1):

I found it's a bootstrap version issue, as original plugin having bootsrap 3.1.0 and your site having 3.3.2

see the difference between two files specially:

3.3.2

```
@media not all, (-webkit-transform-3d)
.carousel-inner>.item.active, .carousel-inner>.item.next.left, .carousel-inner>.item.prev.right {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

3.1.0

```
carousel-inner>.active {
    left: 0;
}
```